# Swift - server socket cannot rebind

Tags: swift, sockets, server

I am trying to program a simple server socket. It is successful to connect to client. But after I disconnect, and try to re-establish the server socket, during binding I got an error (errno = 48, EADDRINUSE). Anyone know how to fix it?

```
func initServerSocket(serverSocket: Int32) -> Int32 {

    var clientSocket: Int32 = -1
    var server_addr_size: Int
    var client_addr_size = socklen_t(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)


    var server_addr = sockaddr_in()
    var client_addr = sockaddr_in()

    server_addr_size = MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size
    memset(&server_addr, 0, server_addr_size);

    server_addr.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
    server_addr.sin_port = UInt16(8080).bigEndian
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = UInt32(0x00000000)


    let bind_server = withUnsafePointer(to: &server_addr) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
            bind(serverSocket, $0, socklen_t(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.stride))
        }
    }

    if bind_server == -1 {
        print("[Fail] Bind Port, Error: \(errno)");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        print("[Success] Binded Port  \(bind_server)");
    }

    if listen(serverSocket, 5) == -1 {
        print("[Fail] Listen");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        print("[Success] Listening : \(server_addr.sin_port) Port ...");
    }

    clientSocket = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &client_addr) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
            accept(serverSocket, $0, &client_addr_size)
        }
    }

    if clientSocket == -1 {
        print("[Fail] Accept Client Connection \(errno)");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        print("[Success] Accepted Client : \(inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr)!) : \(client_addr.sin_port)!");
    }

    return clientSocket
}
```

Disconnect function:

```
func disconnect() {
    if clientSocket != -1 {
        self.inputStream.close()
        self.outputStream.close()

        if close(HiveConfig.clientSocket) == -1 {
            print("serverSocket close error")
        }
        if close(HiveConfig.serverSocket) == -1 {
            print("serverSocket close error")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figure out that on my code before bind need to add the following code to make the address reused.

```
    var opt:Int = 1
    setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, socklen_t(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: opt)));
```